# node app breaking terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, node.js

When I am running Quasar (https://quasar.dev/). When using the `quasar dev` command, it breaks my terminal in a way that there is a black area in the bottom and lines are not refreshed correctly.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/VC5lXoT.png]

[image: https://i.imgur.com/4aovBxU.png]

I have tried zsh but no luck.

I'm using debian WSL.